# Windows 10 RAM Usage: Task Manager vs tasklist command

Tags: windows-10, memory, task-manager

Windows 10 Task Manager shows that I'm using 17.5 GB of RAM, but if I run the following from a command prompt:

```
> tasklist /FO csv
```

load the CSV file into excel, then total the `Mem Usage` column, it only adds up to 8.25 GB. What is using the extra 8.75 GB and why isn't this broken out in tasklist? Is this just some generic OS memory usage that is never explicitly listed?

**Performance > Memory section in Task Manager**

[image]

**Resource Monitor > Memory Tab**

[image]

**Hyper-V is Off**

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the Performance > Memory section in Task Manager?

Comment: @SamForbis See my edit above.  Note memory is usage is currently at 15.2 GB rather than the 17.5 GB mentioned in my post, but tasklist currently only reports 9.77 GB used, so the discrepancy remains.

Comment: There are a number of potential causes, one of which is a memory leak caused by a program or driver. Can you include a screenshot of the memory tab in Resource Monitor?

Comment: Might be a shot in the dark, but do you happen to have Hyper-v enabled?

Comment: @SamForbis See my edit above with the "Resource Monitor > Memory Tab" screenshot.

Comment: @Meow_ly Hyper-V is off, see my screenshot above.

Comment: @user2150989 Thanks for supplying the screenshots. If you add up the memory used in "Working Set" in Resource Monitor, does that number get closer to the total? Also, I see you're using VirtualBox. How much memory do you have dedicated to your virtual machine(s)?

Comment: @SamForbis Is it possible to export the data found in the "Working Set" column of the Resource Monitor window?  I'm not seeing an option to do that and there are too many entries to add everything up by hand.  Also I have allocated 16 GB to VirtualBox within VirtualBox's settings, although it doesn't appear to be using anywhere close to that according to Task Manager.